# Cair no "conto do vigário" é uma expressão tipicamente brasileira ou foi importada de Portugal?

Tags: expressões, origem

O "conto do vigário" é uma expressão comumente usada em pt-BR com o significado de uma história engenhosa inventada por alguém para enganar, lograr ou burlar outra pessoa.  Da pessoa enganada, diz-se que caiu no conto do vigário.

Minha pergunta então é o seguinte:

- É uma expressão usada em pt-PT?
- Quando e onde se originou?
- Porque "do vigário"?  Seria o tal vigário um padre, ou teria a palavra outro significado?

Comment: Só para adiantar uma resposta: sim, não sei mas alguém há-de investigar isso, e [sim](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/vig%C3%A1rio) (como em "ensinar o Pai-Nosso ao vigário").

Comment: @ANeves No Brasil dizemos mais frequentemente "ensinar o padre a rezar".

Comment: Ouço ambas as expressões em frequência similar. Meus familiares do interior de MG, usam mais a citada pelo @ANeves, em SP ouço ambas.

Comment: @Luciano   Então me corrijo. No Rio de Janeiro dizemos mais "ensinar o padre a rezar".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Conto do vigário*** e termos derivados—*vigarista, vigarice, vigarizar*—são de uso corrente também em Portugal. No Google Books e [Corpus do Português] aparecem primeiro no Brasil e cerca de 10 a 25 anos depois em Portugal. Em 1889, a primeira ocorrência que encontrei, [Machado de Assis já se refere ao “famoso conto do vigário”.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=g424CAAAQBAJ&pg=PT1183&dq=%22nem%20ao%20famoso%20conto%20do%20vig%C3%A1rio%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv3Muhm_zUAhVHwBQKHcw8CnQQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22nem%20ao%20famoso%20conto%20do%20vig%C3%A1rio%22&f=false) Em 1903 temos uma referência a [“gatunos batedores de carteiras e vigaristas” (Annaes do Estado de São Paulo)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=yZk9AQAAMAAJ&q=vigaristas&dq=vigaristas&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK7q6trv7UAhXI0RQKHVTiAzA4lgEQ6AEI7gEwHw) e a [“explorações e vigarices” em *Defeza do Coronel João Pereira de Souza*](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=bks&q=%22por%20serem%20muito%20conhecidos%2C%20de%20%2C%20explora%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20e%20vigarices%22&oq=%22por%20serem%20muito%20conhecidos%2C%20de%20%2C%20explora%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20e%20vigarices%22&gs_l=serp.3...4503.7000.0.7566.2.2.0.0.0.0.69.133.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.0.0.mEipvbV_yCU) (um brasileiro).

Em Portugal, temos [*conto do vigário*](http://dicionario-aberto.net/search/vig%C3%A1rio) e [*vigarista*](http://dicionario-aberto.net/search/vigarista) na edição de 1913 do Dicionário de Cândido de Figueiredo, sem indicação que seja brasileirismo. O verbo *vigarizar* é a única expressão que encontrei primeiro em Portugal: [“Tinha sido vigarizada pelo cágado” (Manuel Köpke, *No Sertão d’Africa*, 1926).](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=bks&q=%22Tinha%20sido%20vigarizada%20pelo%20c%C3%A1gado%22&oq=%22Tinha%20sido%20vigarizada%20pelo%20c%C3%A1gado%22&gs_l=serp.3...5581.7898.0.8266.2.2.0.0.0.0.68.135.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.0.0.yC47a3fXUXs)

A origem da expressão, segundo opiniões avançadas já em 1903 e 1904, é a seguinte: o conto do vigário original era literalmente um conto, uma história, apresentada por um pretenso vigário ou outra autoridade religiosa para sacar dinheiro a um incauto. Um comissário de polícia carioca, Vicente Reis, documentou um caso desses no seu livro de 1903 *Os Ladrões do Rio*. O caso ocorreu em 1901, doze anos depois de Machado de Assis se referir ao “famoso conto do vigário”, mas casos semelhantes poderão ter ocorrido antes. Eu não encontrei *Os Ladrões do Rio*, mas o caso é exposto, com abundantes citações, em [*Os Contos e os Vigários* de José Augusto Dias Júnior (2012)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=pbnmtcnphMYC&pg=PT24&dq=%22esse%20bem%20combinado%20artificio%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihl6v22f7UAhXC0xoKHXP8D2AQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22esse%20bem%20combinado%20artificio%22&f=false).

Basicamente um paulista, José Martins Barbosa, recebe em 1901 um carta assinada por um Manuel Suarez Lopes, “padre-parroco” da “Iglesia Parroquial de Santa Maria” em Pamplona, Espanha, dizendo-lhe que um Don Eduaro Martinez Castellanos havia falecido na prisão e deixado uma fortuna e uma filha menor órfã. Esse Don Eduardo tinha em tempos sido forçado a exilar-se no Brasil sob um nome diferente e tinha então conhecido o paulista. Tendo muitos inimigos em Espanha, Don Eduardo transmitira ao padre o desejo que fosse o paulista, homem que tinha em grande conta, a encarregar-se da educação da filha e administração da fortuna. Tudo vinha acompanhado com documentos e carimbos aparentemente oficiais. Resumindo, o padre precisava que o paulista lhe enviasse trezentas libras para custear várias diligências e a passagem da menina para o Brasil. Não se chega a saber se o paulista caiu na esparrela.

No anos seguinte, 1904, Alexandre José de Mello Moraes Filho apresenta a mesma explicação em [*Factos e Memórias*](https://archive.org/stream/factosememorias00filhgoog#page/n57/mode/2up) (grafia original, p. 46):

> Na morena Hespanha […] originou-se o famoso conto do vigario, ha mais de vinte annos em acção no Rio de Janeiro.
>   A principio com distinctivos locaes, crepusculado da religiosidade patria, esse bem combinado artificio girava ao redor de uma dignidade clerical parochiana, de onde lhe deriva o popular nome.

O golpe terá vindo de Espanha, mas não o nome *conto do vigário*, que aparentemente existe apenas em português. Existe no entanto o nome *cuento del tío* na Argentina, Uruguai, Chile e Bolívia para golpes do mesmo género. Mello Moraes Filho continua depois descrevendo o golpe, que essencialmente segue as linha do caso descrito por Vicente Reis. Um vigário ficou encarregue de uma fortuna dum falecido e precisa de dinheiro para a poder desbloquear. [Dias Júnior (2012) sugere que a figura do vigário, acompanhado de carimbos da paróquia, serviria para dar credibilidade à carta. Por esta altura, 1904, chamava-se *conto de vigário* já a outro tipo de golpes também, como convencer a vítima a entregar dinheiro ou outro valor em troca de algo que não tem valor algum, como um pacote de dinheiro que depois se revela ser um maço de papel de jornal. No dicionário de 1913 de Cândido de Figueiredo, [*conto do vigário*](http://dicionario-aberto.net/search/vig%C3%A1rio) designa precisamente este tipo de golpes.

Comment: Um príncipe nigeri... espanhol!

Comment: @ANeves, exatamente. Não há nada de novo debaixo do sol!